# How to replace or append an item in/to a list?

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I've got a list of `case class A(id: Int, str: String)` and an instance of `A`. I need to either replace an item from the list with the new instance or append  the new instance to the list.

```
case class A(id: Int, str: String)
def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] = ???

val as = List(A(1, "a1"), A(2, "a2"), A(3, "a3"))
replaceOrAppend(as, A(2, "xyz")) // List(A(1, "a1"), A(2, "xyz"), A(3, "a3"))
replaceOrAppend(as, A(5, "xyz")) // List(A(1, "a1"), A(2, "a2"), A(3, "a3"), A(5, "xyz"))
```

I can write `replaceOrAppend` like this:

```
def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] =
  if (as.exists(_.id == a.id)) as.map(x => if (x.id == a.id) a else x) else as :+ a
```

This implementation is a bit clumsy and obviously suboptimal since it passes the input list twice. How to implement `replaceOrAppend` to pass the input list just once ?

Comment: Considering `id` as a key, why not using a `Map` rather than `List` ...

Comment: Let's assume that the `replaceOrAppend` signature is given. Of course, you can transform the list to a map, add the element to the map, and then transform the map to a list again. I am just not sure it would be a better approach.

Comment: Why do you need a **List**, does the order matter?

Comment: That looks that an X/Y question (assuming `List` is the right way ...)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes, the input list order does matter.

Comment: @Michael What do you mean with the input list order does matter. That you should return the same order? Does it has to be a List all along, or do you have control over the input? Additionally, have you considered a [**ListMap**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I need to write a function that receives a `List` and returns a `List`. The order of the elements in the output should be the same as in the input.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Let's supposed I don't control the input and should work with a `List` (rather than `ListMap` or any other data structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order is not essential I would go with:

```
def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] =
  a::as.filterNot(_.id == a.id)
```

This would also work if the order is related to `id` or `str`:

```
def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] =
  (a::as.filterNot(_.id == a.id)).sortBy(_.id)
```

And if the order must be kept (as Micheal suggested - I couldn't find anything better):

```
 def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] =
  as.span(_.id != a.id) match { case (xs, ys) => xs ++ (a :: ys.drop(1)) }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if the input list order does matter ?

Comment: so A would always be at the end if appended?

Comment: Yes, `a` should be at the end of `as` if appended.

Comment: what do you think about `def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] = as.span(_.id != a.id) match { case (xs, y :: ys) => xs ++ (a +: ys); case (xs, Nil) => xs :+ a }` ?

Comment: I think that is the best you can do if the order must be kept - I added it to my answer;).

Comment: Thanks, but it looks a little clumsy :(

Comment: maybe a Scala Guru might know a more elegant solution - usually there is one - maybe it needs a bounty;)

Comment: I think I can make the "span" solution a bit nicer using "drop" like that: `def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] = as.span(_.id != a.id) match { case (xs, ys) => xs ++ (a +: ys.drop(1)) }`

Comment: Cool - I didn't know that drop(1) on Nil works - I adjusted my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one:

```scala
def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] = {
  as.find(_.id==a.id).map(op => {
    as.map(el => el match  {
      case e if e.id==a.id => e.copy(str=a.str)
      case _ => el
    })
  }).getOrElse((a::as.reverse).reverse)
}
```

Comment: Looks like your function passes the input list _twice_ but I asked for a function to pass the input _once_. Nice try though :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this? Still clumsy but only uses one iteration.

```
  def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] = {
    val (updatedList,itemToAppend) = as.foldLeft((List[A](),Option(a))) {
      case ((acc, Some(item)), l) =>
        if (item.id == l.id) (acc :+ item, None)
        else (acc :+ l, Some(item))
      case ((acc, None), l) => (acc :+ l, None)
    }
    itemToAppend match {
      case Some(item) => updatedList :+ item
      case None => updatedList
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks clumsy indeed but maybe we can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why people forgets that the best way to handle a functional list is through **pattern matching** + **tail-recursion**.
IMHO, this looks cleaner and tries to be as efficient as possible.

```
final case class A(id: Int, str: String)

def replaceOrAppend(as: List[A], a: A): List[A] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[A], acc: List[A]): List[A] =
    remaining match {
      case x :: xs if (x.id == a.id) =>
        acc reverse_::: (a :: xs)

      case x :: xs =>
        loop(remaining = xs, acc = x :: acc)

      case Nil =>
        (a :: acc).reverse
    }

  loop(remaining = as, acc = List.empty)
}
```

technically speaking, this traverse the list twice on the worst case.
But, it is always better to build a list by prepending from the head and reverse at the end, than to do many appends.